# How can I stop focus from moving to a new cell when I use autocomplete in OpenOffice?

Tags: autocomplete, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc, when I type in a cell, the program can sometimes autocomplete the information from earlier rows in the same column. I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the completion and move to the next row. How can I accept the current completion but stay in the same cell, with my cursor behind the word that was autocompleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to press <kbd>F2</kbd> ("Cell Edit Mode").

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools / options / open office.org Calc / general :under 'input settings' uncheck "Press enter to move selection"

Not one of their better wording examples I fear: "move selection" really means "move the cursor to a new cell", and there are options as to which way it moves.

Answer (score 1):

In google sheets and excel you can press End to auto complete and still remain in the same cell (I've been looking for this one for a very long time and noone knew. Then I found it by accident)

Comment: This doesn't work in oocalc.